# POST method calling from service Angular 6 to the REST using web api in asp.net mvc

Tags: angular, rest, post, asp.net-web-api, cors

OPTIONS http://localhost:51156/api/values 400 (Bad Request)

Failed to load http://localhost:51156/api/values: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400.

in service

```
postTest(student: Student) {

    console.log("In service " + student);
    return this._httpService.post('http://localhost:51156/api/students', student);

}
```

in component.ts calling from front end

```
 postTest(){
    console.log("see now ..."+this.student);
    this.uservice.postTest(this.student).subscribe();
  }
```

front end : HTML data

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="postTest()">TEST</button>
```

errors at console debugging:- google chrome

```
Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable 
the production mode.
user.component.ts:47 see now ...[object Object]
user-service.service.ts:100 In service [object Object]
2zone.js:2969 OPTIONS http://localhost:51156/api/students 400 (Bad Request)
scheduleTask @ zone.js:2969
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ 
zone.js:407
```

GET works fine for me but
POST bad request (POST also works well with the POSTMAN tool so no problem in asp.net web api code) searched lots of websites but doesnt rings bells
With postman i tested json data it works fine with postman
I making mistake while calling http.post() method forgetting something SYNTAX might wrong in 'angular 6'
How you people calls post method from angular
I tested postman works fine
What syntax in angular 6

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:51156/api/students 400 (Bad Request)
Failed to load http://localhost:51156/api/students: Response for preflight 
has invalid HTTP status code 400.
Response {_body: ProgressEvent, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", 
headers: Headers, …}
```

Modified to

```
postTest(){ console.log("see now ..."+this.student); 
console.log(this.student) this.uservice.postTest(this.student).subscribe( 
success => { console.log("success"+success) }, error => { console.log("errrr 
"+error) } ); }
```

and OUTPUT is

```
 errrr Response with status: 0 for URL: null
```

"Help me to solve quick wasted whole two days in this .........."

Hitting

```
  http://localhost:51156/api/students from POSTMAN
```

Passing

`Body{"Sid":1,"fname":"Sss","lname":"XYZ","rollno":666,"address":null,"marks":0," 
    grade":null,"discount":0.0}`

raw JSON (application/json)

then after send clicked
status `200 OK`

Comment: You will need to look at your backend: Why does it throw a 400 error? You might be sending your data in a wrong format/unexpected data/....

Comment: All the things seem ok with your code. Please see your API or Back-End code why is it returning 400. Maybe the problem is that the data you are passing is not acceptable from the API or something else.

Comment: With postman i tested json data it works fine with postman
I making mistake while calling http.post() method forgetting something SYNTAX might wrong in 'angular 6'
How you people calls post method from angular
From postman works fine with status code 200 OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following changes in your code and this issue will be surely resolved.

```
1) In component.ts, I suggest you to call service in the following manner:-

this.uservice.postTest(this.student).subscribe(
        success => {
            if (success.Result) {

            }
        },
        error => {

        }

    );

2) Inside service.ts make these changes : -

 postTest(student: any) {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:51156/api/students/Save,
        JSON.stringify(
            {
                "Student": student
            }), options)
        .map(res => res.json());
}

3) Your API method should be :-

public IHttpActionResult Save([FromBody] StudentModel Student)
```

Comment: it started giving me 

 Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'.


ERROR TypeError: this._httpService.post(...).map is not a function
    at UserServiceService.push../src/app/user-service.service.ts.UserServiceService.postTest

Comment: Import the essentials as 

    
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
   
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

Comment: postTest(){
    console.log("see now ..."+this.student);
    console.log(this.student)
    this.uservice.postTest(this.student).subscribe(
      success => {
        console.log("success"+success) },
      error => {     
        console.log("errrr "+error)
      }     
    );
  } and OUTPUT is  errrr Response with status: 0  for URL: null

Comment: have you checked your API via postman or similar to check whether your API has issues or not?
I have shared the code which is already running at my machine.

Comment: Yes checked perfectly happily running via postman
I afraid angular 6 syntax to do http post method from angular

Answer (score 0):

```
    SOLVED issue using this
```

web.config

```
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
         <customHeaders>
             <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
             <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE" />
         </customHeaders>
       </httpProtocol>
            <rewrite>            
                <outboundRules>
                    <clear />                
                    <rule name="AddCrossDomainHeader">
                        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Access_Control_Allow_Origin" pattern=".*" />
                        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
                            <add input="{HTTP_ORIGIN}" pattern="(http(s)?://((.+\.)?domain1\.com|(.+\.)?domain2\.com|(.+\.)?domain3\.com))" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Rewrite" value="{C:0}" />
                    </rule>           
                </outboundRules>
            </rewrite>
     </system.webServer>
```

put on controller :
 was giving error like multiple allow origin error

```
    [System.Web.Http.Cors.EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:4200", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class StudentsController : ApiController
```

write inside webapiconfig.cs

```
     var cors = new System.Web.Http.Cors.EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:51156", "*", "*");

            config.EnableCors(cors);

            // ADD JUST THIS LINE TO REGISTER FOLLOWING CLASS.
            config.Formatters.Add(new BrowserJsonFormatter());
   // TO SEE DATA IN JSON IN CHROME BROWSER ADD FOLLOWING CLASS BrowserJsonFormatter and REGISTER IN METHOD ADD NEW OBJECT OF THIS CLASS.
public class BrowserJsonFormatter : System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter
{
    public BrowserJsonFormatter()
    {
        this.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
        this.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    }

    public override void SetDefaultContentHeaders(Type type, HttpContentHeaders headers, MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType)
    {
        base.SetDefaultContentHeaders(type, headers, mediaType);
        headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    }
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```